# Having problems fetching XML data from nodes with same name in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm trying to read an XML file through VBA.

I have a node called SCL in which had multiple nodes called IED.

I need to extract the attributes from nodes called FCDA, which every IED has in the same path, `/SCL/IED/AccessPoint/Server/LDevice/LN0/DataSet/FCDA`, and merge them.

The problem is that when I try to run my code, it seems to only get the information on the first IED node and it copies in the others.

What could I be doing wrong?

My code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButtonImport_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
            .Filters.Clear
            .Title = "Selecione um arquivo SCD"
            .Filters.Add "SCD File", "*.scd", 1
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
        If .Show = True Then
            xmlFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
            
            Dim xDoc As Object
            Dim CX As Integer
            Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
            xDoc.async = False: xDoc.validateOnParse = False
            xDoc.Load (xmlFileName)
            
            Set SCL = xDoc.SelectNodes("//SCL/IED")
                For n = 0 To SCL.Length - 1
                    C1 = SCL(n).Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text
                    C2 = SCL(n).Attributes.getNamedItem("manufacturer").Text
                    C3 = SCL(n).Attributes.getNamedItem("type").Text
                    CX = (4 + (3 * n))
                
                    Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(2, CX) = C1
                    Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(3, CX) = C2
                    Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(4, CX) = C3
                                        Set DSI = xDoc.SelectNodes("//LN0/DataSet")
                
                    
                    For j = 0 To DSI.Length - 1
                         'dsName = DSI(j).Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text
                         'dsDesc = DSI(j).Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text
                         'dsX = (4 + (3 * j))
                        
                         'Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(6, dsX) = dsName
                         'Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(7, dsX) = dsDesc
                         
                         Set dsP = xDoc.SelectNodes("//DataSet/FCDA")
                         
                         For k = 0 To dsP.Length - 1
                            
                            ldInst = dsP(k).Attributes.getNamedItem("ldInst").Text
                            Prefix = dsP(k).Attributes.getNamedItem("prefix").Text
                            lnClass = dsP(k).Attributes.getNamedItem("lnClass").Text
                            lnInst = dsP(k).Attributes.getNamedItem("lnInst").Text
                            doName = dsP(k).Attributes.getNamedItem("doName").Text
                            fc = dsP(k).Attributes.getNamedItem("fc").Text
                                
                            dsPoint = ldInst & "." & Prefix & "." & lnClass & "." & lnInst & "." & doName & "." & fc
                            dsPX = (6 + k)
                            
                            If j = 0 Then
                                Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(dsPX, 4) = dsPoint
                            Else
                                Worksheets("Gooses").Cells(dsPX, 4 + (3 * j)) = dsPoint
                            End If
                            
                         Next
                    Next

                Next
            
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And the XML that I'm using:

[Xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15T-IQMClzCZmoiI1rlKlntP_1jbjKqV-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: FYI  - you should close `fd` after retrieving `xmlFileName`.

Comment: For [mcve], please post a *sample* of XML in body of text (be sure to include root) and not in a link that may go dead for future readers.